# linear gradient not working with rgb values calling a function in javascript

Tags: javascript, css

I am trying to generate random background at the click of a button.

I have tried to generate background using random function and linear gradient with rgb values. I have attached my code below.

```
function randomColor() {
    var randomValue = Math.floor((Math.random() * 256) + 0);
    return randomValue;
}

function randomColorClick() {
    var r = parseInt(randomColor());
    var g = parseInt(randomColor());
    body.style.background = "linear-gradient(to right, rgb(randomColor(), randomColor(), randomColor()), rgb(randomColor(), randomColor(), randomColor()))";
}
```

Is there anything wrong about the syntax of linear gradient with rgb values calling the randomColor() function? Please help on this. Thanks

Comment: you are not using the function as a function but as a simple string ... you need to have it outside the string `" ... "+fn()+".."`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You want something like this. Your string doesn't work

```
function randomColor() {
    var randomValue = Math.floor((Math.random() * 256) + 0);
    return randomValue;
}

document.getElementById('yourButton').addEventListener('click', function() {
    var color1 = ' rgb(' + randomColor() + ',' + randomColor() + ',' + randomColor() + '),';
    var color2 = ' rgb(' + randomColor() + ',' + randomColor() + ',' + randomColor() + '))';    
    document.body.style.backgroundImage = "linear-gradient(to right," + color1 + color2;
});
```

Comment: Thanks dstana for your help... It worked for me... Just to be clear body is actually a variable for me like var body = document.getElementById("Gradient") where Gradient is Id for body....

Answer (score 0):

Your function is not called because its concatenated inside your string.
**More Issues:**
1. Use `document.body.style...` and not `body.style...` otherwise it won't work.
2. Change `randomColor()` function logic to be less confusing in the implementation (my suggestion is in the example below).
3. Here is a [working example](https://codverter.com/src/webeditor?query=ebb8d0aa-1874-4342-a854-50d670b13171), based on your code with markers in it.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <style>
    </style>
  </head>
  <body>
    <input type="button" value="go" onClick="randomColorClick()"/>
    <script>
      function randomColor() {
        // creating the whole color value in this function will be less confusing in the implemantion and the code will be more readable and maintainable
        var randomValue = "rgb(";
        for(var i = 0;i<3;i++)
        {
          randomValue += Math.floor((Math.random() * 256)) + (i < 2 ? ",": "");
        }
        // return 'rgb(n1,n2,n3)'
        return randomValue + ")";
      }
      function randomColorClick() {
        var r = parseInt(randomColor());
        var g = parseInt(randomColor());
        document.body.style.background =  "linear-gradient(to left," + randomColor() + "," + randomColor() + " 50%," + randomColor() + "75%, " + randomColor() +" 75%)";
      }
    </script>
  </body>
</html>
```